# How to horizontally centre align a ul within a div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am not sure why this text-align centre isn't taking effect. I've looked up other tutorials and I'm applying the `textalign: center` to the div and then `display: inline` to the ul.

Here is a copy of my HTML code from the browser when inspecting the element as Im actually building a WordPress theme.

```css
#footer-nav.collapse.navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #383434;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px
}
div#footer-nav ul#menu-footer {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul#menu-footer li {
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul id="menu-footer" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li id="menu-item-289" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-289"><a title="About" href="http://localhost/eat-sleep-kayak-wp/about/">About</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-366" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-305 current_page_item current_page_parent menu-item-366 active"><a title="Blog" href="http://localhost/eat-sleep-kayak-wp/blog/">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-290" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-290"><a title="Newsletter" href="http://localhost/eat-sleep-kayak-wp/newsletter/">Newsletter</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-365" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-365"><a title="Advertise" href="http://localhost/eat-sleep-kayak-wp/advertise/">Advertise</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-288" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-288"><a title="Contact" href="http://localhost/eat-sleep-kayak-wp/contact/">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @pol that's the `li` centering not the `ul` @elliot can you use CSS Flex?

Comment: @AkinjideBankole Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @ElliottDavidson I just posted a code pen link below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are using Bootstrap to build it; the default CSS of bootstrap is setting the navbar to `float`, then the `inline-block` property has no effect at all to achieve the center.

This is the default CSS:

```
.navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

You can add to your actual code this :

```
div#footer-nav ul#menu-footer {
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
}
```

[**BootplyDemo**](http://www.bootply.com/pkFPWyRIG0)

Comment: Thanks, can't believe it was just a simple float causing this issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I am using CSS Flex. You can checkout the [codepen link.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqVVwr)

```
#footer-nav.collapse.navbar-collapse {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center; // This centers the ul
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #383434;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

div#footer-nav > ul#menu-footer {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul#menu-footer li {
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
}
```